# Trying to open bootstrap dropdown menu on input checkbox select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to open bootstrap 3 dropdown menu when clicked on input checkbox.
I've tried with 'click' and 'change':

```
$('#my-contacts input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $('#groups').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');
}
```

and also with:

```
$('#my-contacts input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    $('#groups').dropdown('toggle');
}
```

but nothing happend.
when I try on chrome console to launch those functions they works perfect.
but for some reason when I load it from external JS or from html script nothing works.

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem when it works from the console (when content is already rendered but not from script file). Did you wrap your code from your external JS in a `$(function () { CODE_HERE}); ` ?

Comment: Yes, of course its inside $(function() { ......}
Also its the last file to load.

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle or a test page, please? Or at least the related HTML code for both elements.

Comment: Ok, blind guess: If your code works from the console, the element you try to trigger or the dropdown call seems to be correct. So it has to be the change event. Try adding a `e.stopPropagation();` to your on-change callback.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to the `click` event does work if you toggle `.dropdown-menu`:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').delay(200).toggle('slide');
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1835M7gxU3tYVpEEheXf?p=info

Comment: Your example is working better but as you can see in your example it can only work with the checkbox once you clicked on it.
once you clicked the checkbox the dropdown button itself doesn't function any more.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out a way to resolve the issue. You should consider though: should the user be able to open/close the dropdown via both input and button? This would mean having to manage opening/closing via two controls and also unchecking the input when the dropdown closes. A simpler approach could be to have the dropdown disabled by default then enabled on input checked.